# svn log display

Tags: svn

Is there a way to combine `svn log -r 1:HEAD` and `svn log -r {2012-08-02}:{2012-09-03}`

I want to list the svn logs between two dates and display it in descending order.

Either It works for descending order or for two dates. I want to combine both the options -
It should display the log between two dates and in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the order of the dates:

```
svn log -r {2012-09-03}:{2012-08-02}
```

Edit: I assume you already tried this. Perhaps this doesn't work in your version? I have

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
...
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, This was the first option I tried but it didn't work for me since I am using svn, version 1.6.13. Nonetheless, I wrote a small bash script to do the job. Hopefully I will get a new svn version soon. Thanks again !

Comment: For other people finding this question, you should post an answer showing how your script works (I'm guessing it's pretty straightforward) and noting that in newer versions, you can just reverse the date order. If not, at least accept my answer :)